# String Format and Logging primative types - Java

Tags: java, primitive-types

I am trying to write a class that wraps around the logger class in Java. My logging functions are of the form below:

```
public static void LogInfo(String fmt, Object... args) {
    String callerClass = walker.getCallerClass().getName();
    logger.info(String.format("[INFO] [%s] " + fmt, callerClass, args));
}
```

The problem I am having is trying to log primative types, `bool`, `int`, `double`, etc. I have read a little about "Autoboxing" and thought this would work for me but its not.  When I try to log, E.g.

```
int i = 123;
Log.LogInfo("log a number: %d", i);
```

The error I get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

I'm not usually a Java programmer so not sure how to resolve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
String callerClass = walker.getCallerClass().getName();
logger.info(String.format("[INFO] [%s] ", callerClass) + String.format(fmt, args));
```

The problem is when calling String.format() with callerClass and args, Java Varargs creates a new array containing a string and an array, which cannot be displayed by String.format().